# Rename List item when there is the same string multiple time

Tags: c#, wpf, list, linq, combobox

I have `List` of names like:

```
var list = new List<string> {"Allan", "Michael", "Jhon", "Smith", "George", "Jhon"};
```

and a combobox which itemssource is my list. As you can see in the list there is Jhon 2 times, what I want is when I put those name into combobox add "2" to second Jhon. I mean when I open the combobox names in it shoud look like:

```
Allan
Michael
Jhon
Smith
George
Jhon2
```

I have tired linq to do that but I'm quite new to c#/linq. Could someone show me simple way to do that?

Comment: And what should happen when you add 'Jhon' third time?

Comment: Please shared the code you have so far.

Comment: @AleksAndreev 'Jhon3'

Comment: The code in your update won't compile. There is no Name constructor taking six arguments. In the answers, we've shown you how to get a copy of your list with unique names. Then create a `List<Name>` by `var names = uniqueNames.Select(n => new Name(n)).ToList();`

Comment: @Clemens I'm testing al those answers, I'll accept if one of them will work for me

Comment: I mean also on your previous questions.

Comment: Updated question one more time

Comment: I've reverted your second update, because it had absolutely nothing to do with the original question. The current answers clearly show how to create a copy of your name list with numbers attached to duplicate names. In my answer I also show how to create a list if Name objects with unique names. If you have any other problems, ask a new question on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this:

```
var result = list.Take(1).ToList();

for (var i = 1; i < list.Count; i++)
{
    var name = list[i];
    var count = list.Take(i - 1).Where(n => n == name).Count() + 1;

    result.Add(count < 2 ? name : name + count.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I have updated my question, could you check it also please?

Comment: `.Take(i - 1)` should be `.Take(i)`, otherwise this doesn't work for a list like `var list = new List<string> {"Allan", "Allan", "Allan", "Allan", "Allan", "Allan"};`

Comment: The solution does not work for "Allan", "Michael", "Jhon2", "Jhon", "Smith", "George", "Jhon".

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I would do:

First off, separate the list into two smaller ones, one that contains all the unique names, and one that contains only duplicates:

```
var duplicates = myList.GroupBy(s => s)
    .SelectMany(grp => grp.Skip(1));

var unique = new HashSet<string>(myList).ToList();
```

Then process:

```
var result = new List<string>();
foreach (string uniqueName in unique)
{
    int index=2;
    foreach (string duplicateName in duplicates.Where(dupe => dupe == uniqueName))
    {
        result.Add(string.Format("{0}{1}", duplicateName, index.ToString()));
        index++;
    }
}
```

What we are doing here is the following:

- Iterate through unique names.

  - Initialize a variable `index` with value 2. This will be the number we add at the end of each name.
  - Iterate through matching duplicate names.
  - Modify the name string by adding the number stored at `index` to the end.
  - Add this new value to the `results` list.
  - Increment index.

Finally, add the unique names back in:

```
result.AddRange(unique);
```

The `result` list should now contain all the same values as the original `myList`, only difference being that all names that appear more than once have a number appended to their end. Per your specification, there is no name `name1`. Instead, counting starts from 2.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility:

```
var groups = list.Select((name, index) => new { name, index }).GroupBy(s => s.name).ToList();
foreach (var group in groups.Where(g => g.Count() > 1))
{
   foreach (var entry in group.Skip(1).Select((g, i) => new { g, i }))
   {
      list[entry.g.index] = list[entry.g.index] + entry.i;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Someone might be able to give a more efficient answer, but this does the job.

The dictionary keeps track of how many times a name has been repeated in the list. Each time a new name in the list is encountered, it is added to the dictionary and is added as is to the new list. If the name already exists in the dictionary (with the key check), instead, the count is increased by one in the dictionary and this name is added to the new list with the count (from the dictionary value corresponding to the name as the key) appended to the end of the name.

```
var list = new List<string> {"Allan", "Michael", "Jhon", "Smith", "George", "Jhon", "George", "George"};
        Dictionary<string, int> dictionary = new Dictionary<string,int>();
        var newList = new List<string>();
        for(int i=0; i<list.Count();i++){
            if(!dictionary.ContainsKey(list[i])){
                dictionary.Add(list[i], 1);
                newList.Add(list[i]);
            }
            else{
                dictionary[list[i]] += 1;
                newList.Add(list[i] + dictionary[list[i]]);
            }
        }
        for(int i=0; i<newList.Count(); i++){
            Console.WriteLine(newList[i]);
        }
```

Output:

```
Allan
Michael
Jhon
Smith
George
Jhon2
George2
George3
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this solution:

```
public List<string> AddName(IEnumerable<string> list, string name)
{
var suffixSelector = new Regex("^(?<name>[A-Za-z]+)(?<suffix>\\d?)$",
   RegexOptions.Singleline);

var namesMap = list.Select(n => suffixSelector.Match(n))
    .Select(x => new {name = x.Groups["name"].Value, suffix = x.Groups["suffix"].Value})
    .GroupBy(x => x.name)
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Count());

if (namesMap.ContainsKey(name))
    namesMap[name] = namesMap[name] + 1;

return namesMap.Select(x => x.Key).Concat(
    namesMap.Where(x => x.Value > 1)
        .SelectMany(x => Enumerable.Range(2, x.Value - 1)
        .Select(i => $"{x.Key}{i}"))).ToList();
}
```

It handle case when you already has 'Jhon2' in the list

Answer (score 0):

I would do

```
class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var list = new List<string> { "Allan", "Michael", "Jhon", "Smith", "George", "Jhon" };

        var duplicates = list.GroupBy(x => x).Select(r => GetTuple(r.Key, r.Count()))
                             .Where(x => x.Count > 1)
                             .Select(c => { c.Count = 1; return c; }).ToList();

        var result = list.Select(v =>
        {
            var val = duplicates.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == v);
            if (val != null)
            {
                if (val.Count != 1)
                {
                    v = v + " " + val.Count;
                }
                val.Count += 1;
            }

            return v;
        }).ToList();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static FooBar GetTuple(string key, int count)
    {
        return new FooBar(key, count);
    }
}

public class FooBar
{
    public int Count { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public FooBar(string name, int count)
    {
        Count = count;
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

[image]